# Instagram Browser CSRF issues (possibly hidden input issue)

Tags: spring, web, browser, instagram, http-status-code-403

Our Spring application is used to book various services. Normally, our clients list their services in their Instagram bio. When a user clicks the link in the Instagram bio, our application opens up in the Instagram browser.

At a critical point in the flow a 403 is caught by our application. This 403 does not always happen. But when it does, it only happens for **some** users on an iPhone navigating in the Instagram browser. No other combination of device/browser causes it. This 403 is causing us major issues.

The CSRF token is included as a hidden element in the form that is submitted which results in the 403. Perhaps Instagram's browser sometimes ignores this token but how or why is beyone me.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: @WayBehind, negative. Still living with it. Are you seeing something similar?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, we are having some issues with a Django app form displayed through an IFRAME. The Insta browser is not sending all the values. We have even tried to disable the CSRF requirements on the landing page with no success. Apparently, Insta is using UIWebView which is a depreciated version of older Safari browser.

Comment: Very frustrating, especially as much of our clients traffic comes in via Insta. As a workaround, we have added some code to notify us when it happens. We then email the end user and advise them to go via Safari or Chrome. We did try and notify Insta but we may as well have been talking to a field of thistles. If we stumble upon a resolution (no longer actively trying to fix as we wasted so much time on it), I will be sure to post here. BY the way, I don't think IFRAME is part of the issue. At least, we aren't using an IFRAME. We also tried some tricks with CSRF and didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me know if you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with one of my Ruby on Rails projects where people were navigating to a form directly from Instagram profile link, and once in a while we were getting 422's.

Logs showed that Instagram in-app browser submitted CSRF cookie that was different from the token in the hidden corresponding field in the form, which should not be the case, were the page loaded correctly in the in-app browser. We were able to replicate it live on one device, and from user's standpoint page loading and navigation looked completely normal. Could it be related to caching?

Previously we already had default Rails headers with `max-age: 0`, but decided to
simply set

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

for every critical page and see if it changes anything.

The problem seems to have disappeared since.

Comment: This did not solve the issue for us unfortunately.